# PHP Ajax live search only working on localhost

Tags: php, ajax, search, mysqli

I'm creating a search form on a navbar to search for users on a mysql table.

I used a script i found online and, when i used it on localhost it all went fine. As soon as i typed the first letter of a name, i would instantly get the results.

But now, i placed the website on a webserver and what happens is the following:

- I write 1 to 3 letters and nothing happens;
- I write 4/5 letter and a error appears (Fatal error
  : Call to undefined function mysqli_stmt_get_result() in
  /home/pg22933/public_html/jade/backend-search.php
  on line
  68);
- I write almost the full name of a user, and the result finally appears.

This is the file where i have all the code to do this:

```
<?php include('headers.php'); ?>

<script type="text/javascript">

function updateentrada(value, id)
{
 console.log(value, id);
 if(value == 1)
 {
  $.ajax({
  type: 'post',
  url: 'loaddata.php',
  data: {
   idconvidado:id,
   entrada: 0
  },
  success: function () {
    location.reload(); 
  }
  });
 }

 else if (value == 0)
 {
    $.ajax({
  type: 'post',
  url: 'loaddata.php',
  data: {
    idconvidado:id,
   entrada: 1
  },
  success: function () {
    location.reload();
  }
  });
 }
}

</script>


<?php
/* Attempt MySQL server connection. Assuming you are running MySQL
server with default setting (user 'root' with no password) */
$link = mysqli_connect("localhost", "root", "", "jade");

// Check connection
if($link === false){
    die("ERROR: Could not connect. " . mysqli_connect_error());
}

if(isset($_REQUEST['term'])){
    // Prepare a select statement
    $sql = "SELECT * FROM convidados WHERE nome_convidado LIKE ?";

    if($stmt = mysqli_prepare($link, $sql)){
        // Bind variables to the prepared statement as parameters
        mysqli_stmt_bind_param($stmt, "s", $param_term);

        // Set parameters
        $param_term = $_REQUEST['term'] . '%';

        // Attempt to execute the prepared statement
        if(mysqli_stmt_execute($stmt)){
            $result = mysqli_stmt_get_result($stmt);

            // Check number of rows in the result set
            if(mysqli_num_rows($result) > 0){
                // Fetch result rows as an associative array
                while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result, MYSQLI_ASSOC)){
                    $idconvidado = $row["id_convidado"];
                    $nome = $row["nome_convidado"];
                    $entrada = $row["entrada_convidado"];
                    if ($entrada == 1){
                        echo "<button value='". $entrada ."' name='". $idconvidado . "' onclick='updateentrada(this.value, this.name)' class='btnsearch'>" . $nome . " <i class='fa fa-check-circle-o check aria-hidden='true'></i></button>";
                    }
                    else if ($entrada == 0){
                        echo "<button value='". $entrada ."' name='". $idconvidado . "' onclick='updateentrada(this.value, this.name)' class='btnsearch '>" . $nome . " <i class='fa fa-circle-o check aria-hidden='true'></i></button>";
                    }
                }
            } else{
                echo "<p>No matches found</p>";
            }
        } else{
            echo "ERROR: Could not able to execute $sql. " . mysqli_error($link);
        }
    }

    // Close statement
    mysqli_stmt_close($stmt);
}

// close connection
mysqli_close($link);
?>
```

What am i doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.get-result.php

It requires the mysqlnd driver, you need to install it on your web server